# Why don't nested maps in Haskell behave like I would expect?

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to present hierarchy of recursive custom data type Category as a list of strings where each string presents a path to the specific category. The category type looks like this :

```
data Category = Category
 { name :: String
 , sub  :: [Category] }
```

For example, category hierarchy `Category "A" [Category "B" [Category "C" []], Category "D" []]`
in its string representation would look like `["A > B > C", "A > B > D"]` where `" > "` is the delimiter. What I've tried is:

```
printCategories :: [Category] -> [String]
printCategories xs = concatMap (\c -> ((name c)++) <$> (" > " ++) <$> (printCategories $ sub c)) xs
```

The problem is that it always returns empty list `[]` and also it compiles perfectly fine so there are no errors which could lead me to solution.

Comment: I've also tried
    `printCategories' c = [((name c) ++)] <*> (concatMap (\c -> 
    printCategories' c) $ sub c)` for a single category but it gives the same result

Comment: Hint: you presumably want `printCategories [Category "a" []]` to produce `["a"]`, but your function *always* produces a `">"` as a substring of any results. You are missing a base case. Proposal: write `printCategory :: Category -> [String]` instead; the base case will be much more clear.

Comment: Thanks man, just adding the base case for my single category function solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Wagner hinted in comments, all I was missing in my `printCategories'` function which works on single category was the base case `printCategory (Category a []) = [a]` and the solution for the problem was to then `concatMap` the single category function over the list of categories.